# Net Core: Is it Possible to Merge TagBuilder Style Attributes with CSS Files?

Tags: c#, html, css, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

Is it possible to merge style attributes from a Tagbuilder with style attributes coming from CSS/SCSS Files? It seems like Tag builder is totally removing my attributes in SCSS files.
In example below, its only following width from Tag builder and ignoring my other CSS files background color.

```
test.MergeAttribute(
  "style", "width: " + CarouselWidth + @"px;  
  height:" + CarouselWidth + "px; height: 100%;"
);

.test {
  background-color:green
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TagBuilder` is here to help you **build** a HTML element a little bit easily without having to concatenate strings. Should you understand you're building an element from scratch. That means if you don't merge an attribute called "background-color" into the tag builder, it won't have an attribute called "background-color".

The following code should also set the attribute "background-color":

```cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.TagHelpers;

namespace DL.SO.Framework.Mvc.TagHelpers
{
    public class TestTagHelper : TagHelper
    {
        public override void Process(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
        {
            int carouselWidth = 300;

            TagBuilder div = new TagBuilder("div");

            div.MergeAttribute(
                "style", 
                $"width: { carouselWidth }px; height: { carouselWidth }px; background-color: green;");

            output.Content.SetHtmlContent(div);
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Because your post is unclear, based on your "code", I think you should set the attribute `class` as well so that your style could be applied.

```cs
int carouselWidth = 300;

TagBuilder div = new TagBuilder("div");

div.MergeAttribute(
    "style", 
    $"width: { carouselWidth }px; height: { carouselWidth }px;");

div.MergeAttribute(
    "class", 
    "test");
```

[image]

Comment: ok thanks, so you are basically saying I have to set all CSS style properties in TagBuilder, I can't mix them between Tagbuilder and min.css/sass  files, thanks

Comment: No, you don't have to set ALL inline styles in TagBuilder (see my example#2). But in order to style the elements with css/sass files, don't you have to give them a class to start with?